# A function that checks if a given word is a palindrome

Tags: c#

hi I have the following code, and its giving me the error, Palindrome(string) is  a method that is not valid in a given method.

Please help resolve the issue

```
namespace justtocheck
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static bool Palindrome(string word)
    {
       string first = word.Substring(0, word.Length / 2);
       char[] arr = word.ToCharArray();
       Array.Reverse(arr);
       string temp = new string(arr);
       string second = temp.Substring(0, temp.Length / 2);
       return first.Equals(second);

       //throw new NotImplementedException("Waiting to be implemented.");
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Palindrome.IsPalindrome("Deleveled"));
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: there is no `IsPalindrome()` method in this code.

Comment: Hi, still showing some error please refer to testdome.com/questions/c-sharp/palindrome/7282?visibility=1

Comment: you won't learn how to program by asking people to write the answers to your code test questions for you....

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a method and calling an undeclared class' method.
Correct

```
Console.WriteLine(Palindrome("Deleveled"));
```

or change your method declaration

```
public class Palindrome
{
    public static bool IsPalindrome(string word)
    {
       string first = word.Substring(0, word.Length / 2);
       char[] arr = word.ToCharArray();
       Array.Reverse(arr);
       string temp = new string(arr);
       string second = temp.Substring(0, temp.Length / 2);
       return first.Equals(second);
       //throw new NotImplementedException("Waiting to be implemented.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, still showing some error please refer to https://www.testdome.com/questions/c-sharp/palindrome/7282?visibility=1

Answer (score 0):

This is nice and simple:

```
public static bool Palindrome(string word)
{
    var w = word.ToLowerInvariant();
    return w.Zip(w.Reverse(), (x, y) => x == y).Take(word.Length / 2).All(x => x);
}
```